# How to use values passed by jquery/ajax in django view

Tags: ajax, django

How do I retrieve and use the data passed to view via ajax? In this example I'm trying to implement a reddit like upvote/downvote system

html/js:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    {{ post.upvotes }}<button data-id="{{post.id}}" data-vote="up" class="vote" type="submit">Upvote</button>
    {{ post.downvotes }}<button data-id="{{post.id}}" data-vote="down"  class="vote" id="downvote" type="submit">Downvote</button>
{% endfor %}

      <script>
          $(".vote").click(function () {
              var id = $(this).data("id"); //get data-id
              var vote_type = $(this).data("vote"); //get data-vote
          };
          $.ajax({
              url: '/ajax/upvote/',
              data: {
                  'id': id,
                  'vote_type':vote_type,
              }
          });
      </script>
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^ajax/upvote/$', views.upvote, name='upvote'),
```

view:

```
def upvote(request):
    #how do i use 'id' and 'vote_type' values here?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first edit your javascript to send the csrf token, and register a POST url in your `url.py` .

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
    {{ post.upvotes }}<button data-id="{{post.id}}" data-vote="up" class="vote" type="submit">Upvote</button>
    {{ post.downvotes }}<button data-id="{{post.id}}" data-vote="down"  class="vote" id="downvote" type="submit">Downvote</button>
{% endfor %}

      <script>
          $(".vote").click(function () {
              var id = $(this).data("id"); //get data-id
              var vote_type = $(this).data("vote"); //get data-vote
          };
          $.ajax({
              url: '/ajax/upvote/',
              data: {
                  'id': id,
                  'vote_type':vote_type,
                  csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
              }
          });
      </script>
```

Now you can access the data you sent in your `views.py` in a usual way:

```
def upvote(request):
    sentence= request.POST.get("id","")
    upvote = request.POST.get("upvote","") 
    #continue doing your stuffs here...
```

Hope this helps.